# Use FaceTime on MacBook to call via iPhone, being connected to hotspot

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, wifi, wifi-calling

In the [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681) they say that the devices should be connected to the same wifi network:

> - Each device is signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID.
> - Each device is signed in to FaceTime with the same Apple ID.
> - **Each device has Wi-Fi turned on.**
> - **Each device is connected to the same network using Wi-Fi or Ethernet.**
> - On iPhone, go to Settings > Phone > Calls on Other Devices, then turn on Allow Calls on Other Devices.
> - On iPad or iPod touch, go to Settings > FaceTime, then turn on Calls from iPhone.
> - On Mac, open the FaceTime app, then choose FaceTime > Preferences. Click Settings, then select Calls From iPhone.

(emphasis mine)

My MacBook is connected to the Internet using the iPhone hotspot.

By this setup is this supposed to work? I get *call failed*.

However, when I'm home, connected to the router wifi, I can use FaceTime to call using my iPhone (both devices being connected to the router wifi).

Is there any hope to get this working when using Hotspot?

Comment: Could you reference the "documentation"? My guess is your hotspot is blocking the ports needed or throttling that traffic so hard a viable connection with enough bandwidth is lacking. This guide covers basic troubleshooting https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204168

Comment: @bmike I updated the question. Sorry, I posted the question from my phone and I was lazy to copy-paste that list there. :-) So, that means calling via iPhone when connected via hotspot, is supposed to work?

Comment: Do you have Facetime turned on in `Settings -> Cellular`?  If you're using the iPhone hotspot my guess is you're connecting to the internet via cell.

Comment: @fsb That was turned off indeed, but after turning it on and restarting my iPhone the error says that the devices should be on the same wifi network. Do you think there is still any chance to get this running via hotspot?